# jekyll serve fails with "No live threads left"

Tags: rvm, jekyll

I was doing the Quick Start guide on the jekyll site, but when I get to

```
~/myblog $ jekyll serve
```

It crashes immediately with

```
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/jekyll-3.0.0/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:2:in `<module:Jekyll>': No live threads left. Deadlock? (fatal)
```

As you can see, I'm using rvm with ruby-head as my default. Also, this is a recently built Ubuntu 15.10 machine. There is very little cruft, and I've just done the default installs for both rvm and jekyll (from their respective site pages, *not* apt-get).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug. I solved it by doing

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.2
...
$ gem install jekyll
```